# How to find and replace with regex in excel

Tags: regex, excel, replace

I have an excel file with 1 column and multiple rows.

The rows contain various text, here's an example:

```
texts are home
texts are whatever
dafds
dgretwer
werweerqwr
texts are 21412
texts are 346345
texts are rwefdg
terfesfasd
rwerw
```

I want to replace "texts are *" where * is anything after "texts are" with a specific word, for example "texts are replaced". How can I do that in Excel?

Comment: See Office support https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f

Comment: I've read that article and I've tried a few of the examples and also making my own regex, but nothing gave any results. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? I have 2016, I just followed the steps in the "Wildcards for items you want to replace" section, using your example above, and was able to find "texts are *" and replace all instances with "texts are replaced" and it worked as expected, unless I'm misunderstanding

Comment: please refer answer in this question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: @user5796570 , how do I use this? Do I copy paste that code above to a cell as a formula with an `=` equals to sign?

Comment: @AdamAxtmann That article is for Word and doesn't work on Excel 2016.

Comment: Not really regex, but this reply below, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34819759/6266107 , answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As an alternative to Regex, running:

```
Sub Replacer()
   Dim N As Long, i As Long
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 1 To N
      If Left(Cells(i, "A").Value, 9) = "texts are" Then
         Cells(i, "A").Value = "texts are replaced"
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Answer (score 65):

Use Google Sheets instead of Excel - this feature is built in, so you can use regex right from the find and replace dialog.

**To answer your question:**

1. Copy the data from Excel and paste into Google Sheets
2. Use the find and replace dialog with regex
3. Copy the data from Google Sheets and paste back into Excel

Comment: Alternatively, you can use LibreOffice, which supports regular expressions as well.

Comment: questions clearly says "How can I do that in Excel?".

Comment: Too slow for my use case. Page froze for a minute or more for data of size 15,000 rows by 9 columns

Comment: @Mohsen i think the answer is it can't be done in Excel with Regex

Comment: This is the most stackoverflow answer ever. I keep coming back just to make sure it really exists

Answer (score 20):

If you want a formula to do it then:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*texts are *",A1)),LEFT(A1,FIND("texts are ",A1) + 9) & "WORD",A1)
```

This will do it.  Change `"WORD" To the word you want.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Please [edit] this answer to explain how this expression works.  I'm sure this answer is "self-explanatory" for people that work regularly with excel, but for the non-avid user, this pile of commands will likely be incomprehensible.

Answer (score 14):

Apparently, Excel does not use Regex, but there is a workaround. You can use *, ? or ~ in your search pattern.

To find

```
? (question mark) =  Any single character. For example, sm?th finds "smith" and "smyth"  

* (asterisk) = Any number of characters For example, *east finds "Northeast" and "Southeast"  

~ (tilde) followed by ?, *, or ~ = A question mark, asterisk, or tilde. For example, fy06~? finds "fy06?"
```

you can use these combinations to get a similar pattern that will be close to a regex expression.

Comment: can you limit the number of characters?  `?` finds a single character and `*` finds unlimited characters.  what if you want to find unlimited characters?

Also, how do you use grouping to refill some of the characters found in the find (like in regex)

Comment: You can use ?? to replace two characters and ???? to replace four. For unlimited characters you use * but this essentially matches everything till the end of string.

Comment: Other users were correct.  Excel is ill-equipped to do regex search properly.  Better to copy formulas to external txt editor like `notepad++` (find/replace `=` to `/=`; copy formulas to `notepad++`) and then make all your find/replace/regex changes there (keeping the tab separators intact).  Then copy everything back into excel and find/replace `/=` back to `=`

Comment: Notable that this is in the help, but nobody saw it. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Now is 2021 year, you can use **Excel's Replace**

- Key point:

  - Find: `texts are *`
  - Replace: `texts are replaced`
- Steps

  - select content to replace, (upper right corner) choose **replace**

    - [image]
  - in replace popup window, input rule for `Find` and `Replace`

    - [image]
  - click `Replace All`, done ^_^

    - [image]

Comment: Mixing two different languages in your answer is detrimental to the reader.

Comment: Thank you for the Chinese screenshots :)

Comment: are you serios? )) would you like an anwser with arab letters? :))

Answer (score 4):

You can...

1. Exit Excel
2. Make a copy of your Excel file and add to the extension
   (i.e. `.xls` or `.xlsm`) `.xml.zip`.  For example, `test.xls`
   becomes `test.xls.xml.zip`.
3. Unzip the `.zip` file.  Yes, Excel files
   are really `.zip` files.

This will give you a directory named `test.xls.xml` (or `test.xlsm.xml`) that contains the following directory structure: `\xl\worksheets`.

In the `worksheets` directory are your Excel worksheets, in XML format.  They are not formatted for readability, so use an editor that is capable of "pretty" formatting the XML (I use EditPlus or XMLSpy.  There are many out there.).  Now that you can read the XML, you can use the regular expression feature of the editor to make changes.

When you are done, go to the `test.xls.xml` (or `test.xlsm.xml`) directory.  You will see the `_rels`, `docProps` and `xl` subdirectories and the `[Content_Types].xml` file.  Select everything, right click and choose `Send to > Compressed (.zip) folder`.  Make sure there are no `.bak` files left over by your text editor (in the `worksheets` subdirectory).  If they're there, delete them before creating the new `.zip` file.  Now rename the extension of this new `.zip` file to `.xls` (or `.xlsm`).

You can now open this file in Excel.  Excel won't mind that you've "pretty" formatted the XML.

I have done this exact procedure many times, never with any problems (unless I accidently left the `.bak` files laying around).

One word of warning, Excel cells that contain just text (i.e. no formulas) store the text in a different file and reference them from within the worksheet file, so you won't see that text there.  Any text contained in a formula (i.e. `CONCAT("ABC", "DEF")`) is preserved in the worksheet.

Comment: Extremely Surgical but works!